# How do I disconnect various connections from svchost.exe

Tags: windows-8, firewall, blocking, svchost

Resource monitor shows that svchost.exe is connecting to various unneeded locations. How do I disconnect those? I added those addresses to my block list in the Comodo Firewall, but it does not help and it still connects to various unknown locations. One location i.e. is some other local IP provider who I have no business to do with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svchost.exe is a service wrapper that is usually executed multiple times within your system.

Therefore the first step would be to identify the service that performs the unwanted network access. May be it is a separate and unneeded service that can simply be disabled so that it does not start and therefore don't access anything.